# Source client for Icecast video (Theora) streaming?

Tags: gratis, video

I am searching for a source client for [Icecast2](http://www.icecast.org/).

**Required features:**

- Video streaming with OGG Vorbis + Theora
- Capability of alternating live content and content from files.

  - "Bonus points" if mixing is possible as well
- Windows or Linux, or even better, both
- Free, preferably Open Source

I have been researching this for some time, but Google did not have a solution for me.

Comment: What exactly is a "source" client?

Comment: @Caleb You connect to the server using a source client and stream content to it. Then receiving clients also connect to the server and stream the content *from* it.

Comment: Got it, icecast specific terminology then, that's fine!